# Question about a solution to the exercise: Show that $rM=M_s,$ if $\mathrm{gcd}(r,s)=1.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules

The following is taken from *Modules an approach to linear algebra* by Blyth

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Exercise:}$  Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring and let $M$ be an $R$-module.  For every $r\in R$ let $rM=\{rx\mid x\in M\}$, and $M_r=\{x\in M\mid rx=0\}$. Show that $rM$ and $M_r$ are submodules of $M$. In the case where $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, suppose that $n=rs$ where $r$ and $s$ are mutually prime.  Show that $rM=M_s$.

[Hint:  use the fact that there exist $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ra+sb=1$.]

[$\textbf{Solution:}\text{ Last part of the question.}$]

> Note that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}_s\subset r\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, since the set $\{rx\mid x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\}$, for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, contains $\{x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\mid sx=0\}$.  We only need to show the reverse inclusion $r\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}_s$.  Since $\mathrm{gcd}(r,s)=1$, we can find integers $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ so that
> $$
> ra+sb=1_Z.
> \tag{*}
> $$
> Right multiplying $(*)$ on both sides by an element $w\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ gives $(ra)w+(sb)w=1_Z w=w$.  $(sb)w=s(bw)\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}_s$. Also, $(ra)w\in r\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\, (ra)w=1_{\mathbb{Z}} w-(sb)w,\, 1_{\mathbb{Z}} w-(sb)w\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}_s$. We also  have $(sb)w\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}_s$ implies that $(sb)w=0$.  Hence $(ra)w=1_\mathbb{Z} w-(sb)w=1_\mathbb{Z} w\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}_s$. Along with $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}_s\subset r\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, we have $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}_s\subset r\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

Can someone checked if my solution to the above exercise is correct.  I thought I have to judiciously pick some integers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ given $\mathrm{gcd}(r,s)=1$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is correct but way too long. Just notice that for every $w\in M_s,$ $w=raw+bsw=raw\in rM.$ What do you mean by "have to judiciously pick"? (any $(a,b)$ satisfying $(*)$ will do).

Comment: @AnneBauval ah kk.  Thank you.  When I see $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1,$  I keep forgetting if i can just say there exists a pair of integers.... satisfying certain properties beyond them being mere integers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you for the link.